# How can I show gender equality in my photograph?

Tags: digital, ideas

So, basically it's an assignment and I've been asked to capture gender equality and I have no clear idea, it's a school project so they demand decency. If you could just help me out, I'd be obliged.
Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66454/discussion-on-question-by-adi-how-can-i-show-gender-equality-in-my-photograph).

Comment: What images have you made in an effort to capture the theme?

Comment: What does *gender equality* mean to you?

Answer (score 1):

From where I stand, to show gender equality, you need to show men and women (or boys and girls) doing things equally. That's not really that tough. You can show them playing sports together, or doing the dishes together, or whatever other thing you want. You could get topical and show something that's a recent development. For example, just this week Saudi Arabia agreed to let women drive for the first time. If you happen to live there, showing men and women in traffic together would probably qualify.

There are other areas that are dominated by men or women. You might pick one and show both men and women working in such roles. You don't say where you're from, but in the US, tasks like parenting, dance, and nursing tend to be female dominated. Tasks like computer programming, fire fighting, and the military tend to be male dominated. Can you find gender-balanced groups of people doing any of those things? If so, photograph them! If not, try to find other areas. Or go for something that traditionally is balanced and just show that.

Answer (score 0):

Turn your camera on. Take some photos. Look at the images. Process the images. Evaluate the processed images against the assignment. Take more images based on what you learn and repeat. When you run out of time, pick the best image and turn it in.